# Inserting into one column multiple rows - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert into table B a column from table A, hence this query:

`INSERT INTO cuisines(name) VALUES ((SELECT substring_index(Cuisines,',',1) FROM dump));`

But that causes a `1242` error: `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`, I want to insert all these rows, however. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `VALUES` and just insert the select query directly:

```
INSERT INTO cuisines(name)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Cuisines, ',', 1)
FROM dump
```

I don't think that your intended syntax is correct, but the error message seems to be reporting that you are trying to put a multi record result set into a single record of a `VALUES` clause, and obviously that can't work.